# Unity Lighting in 2D, block light source

Tags: unity, 2d, lighting

I'm making a 2D game in Unity, and I want to have characters walking around with flashlights. I've set the 2D sprites to a a Sprites/Diffuse material so they can using unity's lighting system. I want the flashlights to have a realistic lighting effect, in that they can't shine through walls onto other tiles.

I've created a Spot light that uses 'Hard Shadows'. (Pictured Below).
[image]

To illustrate my problem, I've created some cubes to show that the light correctly works with these 3D cubes, in that the light is blocked properly. However, you can see that the light passes through the cube and illuminates the 2D floor sprites PAST the cube.
[image]
[image]

Looks like a problem with orthogonal planes not getting the hard shadows from the cubes.

Is there any way to use Unity's 3D lighting to properly make walls so light doesn't go through objects?
(I've looked at assets in the asset store, the free ones aren't very good and require changing a lot of things).

Comment: Have you tried different shadow types? And are you in Unity free?

Comment: @n_palum Yeah I've tried Soft Shadows, and fiddled with the Shadow Type settings (bias, strength, etc). I am using Unity Free.